# Python Boolean mask using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean, time-series

I am trying to compute a value given a condition on the time of day. The vectors/series are the net solar radiation for a given hour and the time the data was colected. When the value was obtained during daylight I have to multiply said value by .1, and when the value was obtained in nighttime I multiply the value by .5. The thing is that the daylight hours change noticeably month by month (week by week even) as the daylight dictionary shows below:

I'm trying to create a boolean mask (withindaylight) which would help me apply the calculation/multiplication WITHOUT using a for-loop over every value in the 'time' vector and and checking it against daylight dictionary which is what I'm currently doing:

```
def Ghr(time, Rn):
    #soil heatflux cal
    #time is a single vale of the time vector
    mon = time.strftime('%b') #strips the month

    #sunrise -sunset hours from 1st of the month (sr,ss) to end of the month
    #Jan-1st SR 8:17, Jan-31st SR 07:47
    #Jan-1st SS 16:03, Jan-31st SS 16:52

    daylight = {'Jan':('08:00', '16:25'),
            'Feb':('07:20', '17:20'),
            'Mar':('06:45', '18:40'),
            'Apr':('06:05', '20:05'),
            'May':('05:10', '20:55'),
            'Jun':('04:50', '21:25'),
            'Jul':('05:10', '21:15'),
            'Aug':('05:50', '20:30'),
            'Sep':('06:45', '19:25'),
            'Oct':('07:00', '17:30'),
            'Nov':('07:25', '16:15'),
            'Dec':('08:05', '16:00')}

    #strips the hour and minute from the daylight dictionary
    #then withindaylight is the boolean  after checking the
    #time the data was collected against the these stripped values

    daybegin = dt.strptime(daylight[mon][0], '%H:%M').time()
    dayend= dt.strptime(daylight[mon][1], '%H:%M').time()

    withindaylight = daybegin <= time.time() <= dayend


    #I want to apply the boolean mask such that it produces the following,
    #but returns a vector and not just a single value

    if withindaylight:
        return .1*Rn   #I want to return a series and not just a single value

    else:
        return .5*Rn
```

Answer (score 1):

There were several things that needed to happen with my code:

1. How to make sure that each instance of my 'time' was mapped to correct month as the key from the 'daylight'...
2. How to extract the tuple to a separate list
3. conversion of the tuple holding the string into a time object in a pd.Series
4. converting to a mask and applying the multiplication

I solved these issues with the following code:

```
def Ghr(time, Rn):
    """Soil Heat flux calculator"""

    #sunrise -sunset hours from 1st of the month (sr,ss) to end of the month
    #Jan-1st SR 8:17, Jan-31st SR 07:47
    #Jan-1st SS 16:03, Jan-31st SS 16:52  

    daylight = {'Jan':('08:00', '16:25'),
            'Feb':('07:20', '17:20'),
            'Mar':('06:45', '18:40'),
            'Apr':('06:05', '20:05'),
            'May':('05:10', '20:55'),
            'Jun':('04:50', '21:25'),
            'Jul':('05:10', '21:15'),
            'Aug':('05:50', '20:30'),
            'Sep':('06:45', '19:25'),
            'Oct':('07:00', '17:30'),
            'Nov':('07:25', '16:15'),
            'Dec':('08:05', '16:00')}

    #this maps the month of 'time' as to the dictionary daylight
    #then unzips the tuple to daystart and dayend lists which 
    #are then converted to pandas.Series objects for use in boolean mask
    daystart, dayend = zip(*time.dt.strftime('%b').map(daylight))

    #dt.strftime extracts the 'Mon' ('%b') from the DateTime object and
    #maps it to the dictionary and saves the morning and dusk hours respectively

    #conversion to pandas series
    daystart=pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(daystart).time)
    dayend=pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dayend).time)
    t=pd.Series(time.dt.time)
    #the above converts the strings to datetime objects and saves it
    #to a pandas Series, t is just a to_Series conversion


    light_mask = t.between(daystart, dayend)
    #this mask will be used to designate which values get multiplied by
    #either .1 or .5


    #True values get multiplied by .1 (The inversion is because 
    #pd.Series.where() only changes the values which are False)
    Ghr = Rn.where(np.invert(light_mask), Rn*.1)

    #False values multiplied by *.5
    Ghr = Rn.where(light_mask, Ghr*.5)

    return Ghr
```